Google Sheet Cell Appearing Blank Despite Returning Value
I have a google sheet that's meant to calculate some things for me and uses complex formulas. In multiple cases, when I click into the cell and select all, it shows the expected value. However, the cell is still visually blank and when I ran a =(LEN(B4) to test it, it said the length was zero.
I have the following formula:
=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&(INDIRECT("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&"$B$2"))))),"",INDIRECT(("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&(INDIRECT("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&"$B$2")))))


If I select the entire formula, it shows as 66 as it should. I've tried copying and pasting the formula and the only thing that has worked is dragging the formula from another cell again. This is happening in all locations where this formula are used but once I've dragged the formula over, it displays the correct value. The formatting is black on white like usual, so it's not like I just don't have it visible. If I change the value of any cell it references, the cell again goes "blank" and I have to re-drag it in order for it to work.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible sample, ?

The formula is in cell B3. If A4=Drawing and B1=1st, then it will look for another sheet called "Drawing 1st", get B2 of that sheet which refers to another cell, so "M1" would have it get the value from M1 of the "Drawing 1st" sheet

Can you provide a sample data on a sheet, this way the community will have better oversight on how your project works and will have a better idea what is happening?

indirect() formulas often cause performance issues, especially when copied over many cells. There are usually much better ways to look up data, including functions like filter(), query(), and vlookup() with match(). These functions are also easy to apply over a range of cells in one go using an array formula.
The formula uses four instances of indirect():

=IF( 
 ISERROR(INDIRECT(("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&(INDIRECT("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&"$B$2"))))), 
         "", 
         INDIRECT(("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&(INDIRECT("'"&$A4&" "&B$1&"'!"&"$B$2")))) 
)


You can improve performance by simplifying the formula to two indirect() instances like this:
=iferror(indirect($A4 & " " & B$1 & "!" & indirect($A4 & " " & B$1 & "!" & "B2")))

...and further apply DRY like this:
=let( 
  sheetRef, $A4 & " " & B$1 & "!", 
  cellRef, indirect(sheetRef & "B2"), 
  iferror(indirect(sheetRef & cellRef)) 
)

To improve spreadsheet performance further, see my optimization tips.
